# libgdx doesn't render fonts properly after resume

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm having problems with fonts using libgdx on android. They work fine when i first open the application. But when I pause the app then resume it, the fonts are rendered incorrectly.

Here's how I create the font.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/MainFont.ttf"));
LabelStyle ls = new LabelStyle();
ls.font = generator.generateFont(30);
ls.fontColor = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);       
mPlay = new Label("Play", ls);      
mInstructions = new Label("How To Play", ls);
generator.dispose();
```

I don't have anything in my Pause/Resume methods, not sure if there should be something there.

Here's what it looks before/after like.

[image: Before]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a known issue of the LibGDX framework. If it's your case, this bug is solved in newer versions of the framework.

More info on the official issues tracker: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/870

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like that's it. They say it should be fixed in 0.9.9, which is what i'm using. Another thread linked from there has a few people saying it's working now and some saying it still isn't working. Looks like I might be able to work around it by just reloading the fonts on resume for now. I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: Reloading the font sure will work, but the issue should be fixed by now, probably not in the 0.9.9 release, but have you tried on the nightlies? I always recommend using the nightlies build :)

Answer (score 2):

```
generator.dispose();
```

remove this line 
and put it in dispose method
your font is getting dispossed.